Alter geometry after UV unwrap with Geometry Nodes
I am working on a rope simulation.
In order to make it realistic, I use a Displace shader to get the bumps of the individiual strings of the rope. Because of the rope strings are 45 degrees I want my geometry to have 45 degrees edges as well otherwise the displacement shader is jagged and I need too much subdivisions to smooth it out.
So I got the following Node set-up for the geometry: It's basically a mesh line with a Profile Curve of a Spiral with 0 height, to act as a easily UV unwrappable Curve Circle. After that I 'poke' the faces with an Extrude Mesh and Merge by Distance node, so it has the diagonal lines.

But here comes the trouble: my perfect unwrapped UV is also getting extrudes and stuff. Is there a way to keep the unwrapped UV before altering the geometry?
I'm new to geonodes, and I've been trying everything I can think off. I think I am really close now, but just cannot fix this.
Download the file:

I used this method for the UV unwrap:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9LOxkoX-yY&t=139s
